# Can Anyone Fly A Plane?

Tags: emergency

Have it ever happened that the flight attendants asked the most wanted and feared question of all flight-simmers out there: "Can Anyone Fly A Plane?"

My question is for events when all the pilots was incapacitated, and someone who in not a qualified pilot landed the plane.

Comment: Only in the movies.  And then Kurt Russell steps in to save the day.  Far more likely to ask for a Doctor to help with another passenger.

Comment: @CrossRoads How do you know that? It has actually happened.

Comment: That's why I commented, vs answered.  If there's a flight attendant, there's usually a first officer - guess who'd be flying then?

Comment: It actually gets said as "**any non-revenue pilots, please push your call button**".  If you heard it, you'd disregard it as technobabble, but it's a dogwhistle to pilots with any experience.